# TextToSpeech how to know when speech is finished with speeking

Tags: android

```
TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(context, this);
tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

how can i know when speech is finished with speaking, becouse when stop talking i need to execute some extra code. But i have problem becouse i don't knowh how to check if speech is finished with talking.

Is there any option to check this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there are two listeners:

- API 4-14: [OnUtteranceCompletedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener.html)
- API 15+: [UtteranceProgressListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/UtteranceProgressListener.html)

---

I haven't used the UtteranceProgressListener, but the OnUtteranceCompletedListener is very particular. Here are two tips:

- Set this listener in the `onInit()` callback, never before.
- You must pass the third parameter `params` to `speak()` with a valid `KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID`, otherwise this listener is never called.

Answer (score 1):

As for as i know there is no listener for this but we have method called `isSpeaking()` to check  whether TTS engine is busy speaking or not. So that you can take the help of this method to check it is speaking or not

Answer (score -1):

```
public boolean isDoneSpeaking() {
                   if(!mTts.isSpeaking())
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }
```

Comment: This is a complicated way of just using `if(!mTts.isSpeaking())` by itself.

Comment: This is useful when using it outside the class so that you dont have to reference to the TTS object.

Comment: Ok, if you want to protect `mTts` this will work, but you can simplify this method to `return !mTts.isSpeaking()`. I looked into this question myself and did find a listener that is called after the synthesizer finishes.